# How to return all values of a JS class to HTML

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm taking a javascript class in school and we just started OOPs. I'm struggling to understand how to return all of an object's properties to an HTML paragraph, division, etc.

Here's the code in question:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.describeMyself = function(){
      return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "My name is " + this.firstName;
    }
  }

  var john = new Person("John", "Smith", 53, "male");
  john.describeMyself();
```

This works to output the first name but I need to output ALL the values.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can manually output them all.

Comment: Yes, but is there a more concise, efficient way?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b82byus/1/ Is this something you want?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling to understand how to return all of an object's properties to an HTML paragraph, division, etc.

To return all objects properties to the html, in a similar way you are doing, will be to include them on your `this.describeMyself` function or you can create a new function eg `this.allProperties`

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.lastName = lastName;
 this.age = age;
 this.gender = gender;
 this.describeMyself = function(){
  return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "My name is " +
   this.firstName;
 }

 // You can keep this function, modify it or modify your describe myself.
 this.allProperties = function(){
  return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "My name is " +
   this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "and I'm a "+ this.age +" year old " + this.gender;
 }
}

var john = new Person("John", "Smith", 53, "male");
john.allProperties();
```

This would print in your #id tag:

My name is John Smith and I'm a 53 year old male.

You can modify the text so that it returns whatever you want but the idea is to create a function that returns `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML` and then you can add the properties that you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a method for each. You are doing it right. I am assuming that you want to print something like:

My first name is `this.firstName`.
My last name is `this.lastName`.
My age is `this.age`.

In that case, a method for each will do the job.

Or alternatively, you can first get an array of all the properties by using `Object.keys()` method.

Then loop through that array.

Assuming your sentence structure is going to be the same each time:

```
"My " + propertyName + " is: " + propertyValue.


function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;

  }

  var john = new Person("John", "Smith", 53, "male");

var su = Object.keys(John);

for(var i = 0; i < su.length; i++) {
 console.log(console.log("My " + su[i] + " is " + john[su[i]]))
}
```

I hope this helps.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The properties on your Person will just be the keys on an Object, so if you want to write a function that will always output all properties you can use Object.keys() to iterate through your object's properties:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.getAllProps = function() {
    return Object.keys(this).reduce(function(p, n){
      if (typeof this[n] === 'function') {
        return p;
      } else {
        return p + this[n] + ', ';
      }
    }.bind(this), '');
  },
  this.describeMyself = function(){
    return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.getAllProps();
  }
}
```

This is assuming you just want to output your property values only, with no sentence structure.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work just fine. 
You can simply keep using the + operator to continue putting together the string that will be output in the div.

Here's an example

[A codepen demo](http://codepen.io/pastranastevenaz/pen/KNeVvx)

I hope this helps

`function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.describeMyself = function(){
          return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "My name is " + firstName + " " + lastName +"." + " I am.....";
        }
      }`

Answer (score -2):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.describeMyself = function(){
      return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "My name is " + this.firstName + ", I'm a " + this.age + " year old " + this.gender + " StackOverflow leecher";
    }
}

var john = new Person("John", "Smith", 53, "male");
john.describeMyself();
```